# How to effeciently count string aliases?

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections, count, counter

I'm working on a personal project that counts instances of names mentioned in text. I know I can do it with `collections.Counter()` but I'm not sure how to account for aliases efficiently.

So for example let's say one of the names I want to count is `"Tim"` but I would also like to count any nicknames he has like `"Timmy"` and `"Timster"`.

I have some strings saying, `"Oh Tim is going to the party?"`, `"Yeah, my boy Timmy, wouldn't miss it, he loves to party!"`, `"Whoa, the Timster himself is going? Count me in!"`

Which I'd like to all count as under a variable like `"Tim"`. I know I could simply individually count them all and then add the counts together. But I feel like there is a better way I could do it.

I.E. I want my code to look more like.

```
names = {
    'Tim':{'Tim', 'Timmy', 'Timster'},
    ... other names here.}
# add any occurrence of Tim names to Tim and other occurrences of other names to their main name.
```

As opposed to something like

```
total_tim = Counter(tim) + Counter(timmy) + Counter(timster), etc..
```

for each name. Does anyone have any idea how I would go about doing this?

Comment: `total_tim = Counter(tim) + Counter(timmy) + Counter(timster), etc..` is more straightforward, and will likely be more efficient than added indirection. You can maybe wrap this approach into methods that mimick your preferred choice?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Are you sure? I was planning on tracking dozens of names and feel like manually adding them all together feels really sloppy.

Comment: One way or another, you have to input these alias groups, don't you? If you wrap it in a `class AliasCounter` for instance; that class can take a `text Counter`, and group it by aliasses; you still need to provide these aliasses though.

Comment: @ChristianDean Sorry, I'm not really sure how I would do that without having to add all the aliases together manually like how I'm trying to avoid. Can you give an example?

Comment: How would you teach your computer that `tim`, `timmy`, and `timster` are aliasses, but not `timber`?

Comment: why not just use counter, and then combine all that starts with tim

Comment: @Kalyan Because there are many names. Say for example if I use Richard, it could be "Rich", "Rick", or "Dick".

Comment: so, you want to make a dict? and then use them to group?

Comment: @Kalyan More or less, yeah. I want to store a list of nicknames for a set name, on a scale of dozens of names, to then count how many times a name appears (by counting nicknames as appearances of the name it belongs to)

Comment: you already have a solution and looking for a efficient one or you just want a functioning solution?

Comment: I already have a solution. (I could simply use Counter() to add each nickname individually and then say Tim = Tim_Counter + Timmy_Counter + Timster_Counter and so forth for every name, but that would take up a lot of lines when working with dozens of names.) I'm hoping to find a solution that can just say "count the appearances of all nicknames in this dict, for each name in the dict."

Comment: @ArnoldM904, i used regex and wrote an answer, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using regex will help solve this.

```
import re
your_dict = {"Tim":["Tim","Timmy","Timster"]}
s = "Oh Tim is going to the party? Yeah, my boy Timmy, wouldn't miss it, he loves to party! Whoa, the Timster himself is going? Count me in!"
for each in your_dict:
    print(each,"count = ", len(re.findall("|".join(sorted(your_dict[each],reverse=True)),s)))
```

If you want to ignore case, then just use `re.IGNORECASE` parameter in the `re.findall`

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter

TEXT = '''
    Blah Tim blah blah Timmy blah Timster blah Tim
    Blah Bill blah blah William blah Billy blah Bill Bill
'''
words = TEXT.split()

# Base names a their aliases.
ALIASES = dict(
    Tim = {'Tim', 'Timmy', 'Timster'},
    Bill = {'Bill', 'William', 'Billy'},
)

# Given any name, find its base name.
BASE_NAMES = {a : nm for nm, aliases in ALIASES.items() for a in aliases}

# All names.
ALL_NAMES = set(nm for aliases in ALIASES.values() for nm in aliases)

# Count up all names.
detailed_tallies = Counter(w for w in words if w in ALL_NAMES)

# Then build the summary counts from those details.
summary_tallies = Counter()
for nm, n in detailed_tallies.items():
    summary_tallies[BASE_NAMES[nm]] += n

print(detailed_tallies)
print(summary_tallies)

# Counter({'Bill': 3, 'Tim': 2, 'Timmy': 1, 'Timster': 1, 'William': 1, 'Billy': 1})
# Counter({'Bill': 5, 'Tim': 4})
```

Comment: There will be problems when word are separated by other than whitspace: 'Tim, blah blah.'

Comment: @figbeam Sure, but that wasn't the question asked.

Comment: This does require you to explicitly name every alias also.

Comment: @WStokvis Yes, but they are named as **data**. They are not encoded in variable names (eg `total_tim = Counter(tim) + Counter(timmy) + Counter(timster)`).

Comment: this is definitely not a efficient way

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple solution using regex.

What's good about this solution is you don't have to explicitly name the variations. If you know the beginning variations of that person's first name, you should be fine.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

TEXT = '''
    Blah Tim blah blah Timmy blah Timster blah Tim
    Blah Bill blah blah William blah Billy blah Bill Bill
'''

tim_search = '(Tim([a-z]*)?(?=\ ?))'
bill_search = '((B|W)ill([a-z]*)?(?=\ ?))'
def name_counter(regex_string): 
   return Counter([i for i, *j in re.findall(regex_string, TEXT)])

name_counter(tim_search)
Counter({'Tim': 2, 'Timmy': 1, 'Timster': 1})

name_counter(bill search)
Counter({'Bill': 3, 'Billy': 1, 'William': 1})
```